# Rebus: Is it not possible to use Rebus.Castle.Windsor along with Rebus 5.3

Tags: rebus

While trying to use rebus castle windsor along with rebus 5.3 then giving compile time error that "IHanlderActivator" is defined in an assembly which is not referenced, must add a reference to assembly rebus 4.0

[image: Error with rebus 5.3 for rebus castle wind]

Is rebus castle windsor only compatible with rebus 4.0 now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's certainly possible.

I've just created a Console Application (.NET 4.7.2) and installed the

- `Rebus`
- `Rebus.Castle.Windsor`
- `Rebus.XmlConfig` (because I can see you're using that)

NuGet packages, which in turn resulted in the following packages.config:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Castle.Core" version="4.2.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Castle.Windsor" version="4.1.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="11.0.1" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Rebus" version="5.3.1" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Rebus.Castle.Windsor" version="4.1.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Rebus.XmlConfig" version="4.0.0" targetFramework="net472" />
</packages>
```

With this little program:

```cs
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            using (var container = new WindsorContainer())
            {
                Configure.With(new CastleWindsorContainerAdapter(container))
                    .Transport(t => t.UseInMemoryTransport(new InMemNetwork(), "windsor-test"))
                    .Routing(r => r.TypeBasedRoutingFromAppConfig())
                    .Start();

                Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER to quit");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get this:
[image: picture of console application running]

Could you try and check e.g. how your packages.config differs from mine?

Comment: You are right , It is working with 5.3 version but I am using signed version of rebus 5.3 and somehow getting above error but if I use unsigned one then works fine !! So I will try with unsigned rebus 5.3 & strongnamer nuget package.

However with signed version of rebus 4.0, I am not getting that error. that is strange.

Comment: You're using a signed version of Rebus 5.3? Where did you get that?

Comment: I just signed it using our SNK as we are using signed assemblies within our projects. And before signing Rebus 5.3 I also went through various blogs and your comments on same :) and find out that its not that useful to have signed assembly but I had no choice due to project dependency.